# Saving image file in custom entity using entity_metadata_wrapper

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to save a file in a custom entity and cannot nail it. I have a custom entity called companies, the entity has a custom field called company_logo.

I've got a form with a file upload field. This all works fine.
Where I'm coming unstuck is saving the file information to the field.
I've tried this:

```
// Get file info.
$file = file_load($form_state['values']['company_logo']['und'][0]['fid']);

// Initiate wrapper.
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('company',$form_state['build_info']['args'][0]->company_id);

// And set the logo.
$wrapper->company_logo->file->set($file);

// And save the entity.
$wrapper->save();
```

But no joy.
Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of `entity_metadata_wrapper` must be an object.

```php
// Get file info.
$file = file_load($form_state['values']['company_logo']['und'][0]['fid']);

// Initiate wrapper.
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('company',$form_state['build_info']['args'][0]);

// And set the logo.
$wrapper->company_logo->file->set($file);

// And save the entity.
$wrapper->save();
```

Comment: If you got other Drupal problems in future, you can post question in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: I have taken note of this and will use that in future. Sweet cat avatar btw. :)

Comment: It's not mine, but my neighbour's in the past. Anyway, thanks! ;)